# Alfresco web scripts: How do I stop processing or return early?

Tags: alfresco

I have a web script in Alfresco that works when I pass in the correct arguments in my HTTP request. I have added validation similar to this snippet ([source](http://docs.alfresco.com/3.4/tasks/ws-controller-create.html)).

**How can I tell Alfresco to stop processing the webscript if I find that my validation steps have failed?** (If possible, I would like to do this without an else block.)

```js
// extract folder listing arguments from URI
var verbose = (args.verbose == "true" ? true : false);
var folderpath = url.templateArgs.folderpath;

// search for folder within Alfresco content repository
var folder = roothome.childByNamePath(folderpath);

// validate that folder has been found
if (folder == undefined || !folder.isContainer) {
   status.code = 404;
   status.message = "Folder " + folderpath + " not found.";
   status.redirect = true;
   // ********* HOW DO I TELL ALFRESCO TO STOP PROCESSING HERE? ************
}

// perform some business logic with the parameters that passed validation......
// ********* I DO NOT WANT TO COME HERE IF VALIDATION FAILS ************

// construct model for response template to render
model.verbose = verbose;
model.folder = folder;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick here is to wrap your code in a function (usually called `main` by convention). Just call that function and return from that function if you want to stop processing. Like so:

```
function main() {
  // extract folder listing arguments from URI
  var verbose = (args.verbose == "true" ? true : false);
  var folderpath = url.templateArgs.folderpath;

  // search for folder within Alfresco content repository
  var folder = roothome.childByNamePath(folderpath);
  // validate that folder has been found
  if (folder == undefined || !folder.isContainer) {
    status.code = 404;
    status.message = "Folder " + folderpath + " not found.";
    status.redirect = true;
    return;
  }
  // Do stuff with the folder

}

main();
```

Comment: Nice and very simple.